# Yeoman - Delaying logging until after task completion

Tags: javascript, yeoman

I'm getting frustrated with part of a Yeoman Generator I'm building. As it's my first, I have no doubt I'm missing something obvious, but here it goes.

Simply put, I'm trying to log a message, Do Things™ and then log another message **only when those things have been done**.

Here's the method:

```
repos: function () {
    var self = this;

    this.log(highlightColour('Pulling down the repositories'));

    // Skeleton
    this.remote('user', 'skeleton', 'master', function(err, remote) {
      if (!err) {
        remote.bulkDirectory('.', self.destinationRoot());
      } else {
        self.log('\n');
        self.log(alertColour('Failed to pull down Skeleton'));
        repoErr = true;
      }
    });

    //
    // Three more near identical remote() tasks
    //

    if (!repoErr) {
      self.log(successColour('Success!'));
      self.log('\n');
    } else {
      self.log(alertColour('One or more repositories failed to download!'));
    }
  },
```

Each of the individual remote() tasks are working fine, but I get both the first and last self.log() messages **before** the file copying happens. It seems trivial, but I simply want the success message to come **after** everything has been completed.

For example, in the terminal I see:

> Pulling down the repositories
>
> Success!
>
> ***file copying results***

It should be:

> Pulling down the repositories
>
> ***file copying results***
>
> Success!

I thought it could be something to do with using this.async() with done() at the end of each remote() task, and I tried that, but whenever I do, none of the code fires at all.

I've even tried breaking everything (including the messages) into separate methods, but still no luck.

Such a simple goal, but I'm out of ideas! I'd be grateful for your help!

EDIT: In case you're wondering, I know the messages are coming first because any alerts regarding file conflicts are coming **after the messages** :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an issue related to Yeoman. You have asynchronous code, but you're handling it as if it was synchronous.

In the example you posted here, just do the logging as part of `this.remote` callback:

```
repos: function () {
  var self = this;

  this.log(highlightColour('Pulling down the repositories'));

  // Skeleton
  this.remote('user', 'skeleton', 'master', function(err, remote) {
    if (!err) {
      remote.bulkDirectory('.', self.destinationRoot());
      self.log(successColour('Success!'));
      self.log('\n');
    } else {
      self.log('\n');
      self.log(alertColour('Failed to pull down Skeleton'));
      self.log(alertColour('One or more repositories failed to download!'));
    }
  });
},
```

Maybe your actual use case is more complex; in this case you can use a module like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) (or any other alternative) to handle more complex async flow. Either way, Yeoman doesn't provide helpers to handle asynchronous code as this is the bread and butter of Node.js.

Comment: In general, what's the best way to approach forcing a synchronous order? Multiple generators?